# What do singular complexes look like?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the construction of singular homology (from Hatcher), we can reduce it to a case of simplicial homology by defining the singular homology groups as the simplicial homology groups of its singular complex. I know a singular complex consists of an $n-$simplex for every possible continuous image of an $n-$simplex. So clearly the singular complex has an extremely large number of simplices of all dimensions. My question is what exactly do singular complexes look like, and how can we be sure its homology groups line up with those of our initial space?

Comment: It's indeed not clear how $H_n^\Delta(S(X))$ is isomorphic to $H_n^\Delta(X)$. It'd be insane to try to do it by visualizing $S(X)$, it's a very large, dumb space. The standard proof is to do homological algebra trickery, look in the very end of Hatcher chapter 2.1.

Comment: The statement that the simplicial homology of the singular complex is the same as the singular homology of the original space is pretty much immediate from the definition (there is an obvious isomorphism between the chain complexes that define them, since there is a bijection between the simplices of the singular complex and singular simplices in the original space, and this bijection preserves boundaries).